# How to remove elements from a char[]?

Tags: d

I have a `char[]` with characters. I want to remove whitespaces. My approach:

```
import std.algorithm;
import std.ascii;
// ...
digits = remove!"isWhite(digits)"(digits);
```

But this doesn't work:

```
c:\dmd2\windows\bin\..\..\src\phobos\std\functional.d(70): Error: static assert  "Bad unary function: isWhite(digits) for type dchar"
```

How do I remove all whitespaces from a `char[]`?

Answer (score 4):

```
import std.algorithm;
import std.stdio;
import std.uni;
import std.array;

void main() {

    char[] s = "12 abc fg ".dup;

    writeln(array(s.filter!(x => !x.isWhite)));
}
```

[`array`](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_array.html#array) is needed to get rid of the `Result`-returntype of `filter`. But you don't have to do it, if you want to work with `Ranges`.

Comment: Thanks. `filter` also caught my eye but I thought `remove` was the right choice.

Comment: I chose filter, since it's a really powerful tool in combination with the new lambdas (and it looks pretty neat with UFCS). E.g. you can remove all whitespaces and a special set of chars and all digits and the characters `ABF` in one go.

Answer (score 2):

A more economic version (that doesn't do memory allocation) is to use std.algorithm.remove like this (untested):

```
s = remove!isWhite(s);
```

Your initial attempt to use remove used a lambda for the entire string, but it needs one for one character only.

Comment: I can only get this to work if I convert the string to dchar[]: s = remove!isWhite(to!(dchar[])(s));